# Where is the object in the example sentences for definition #2 of the verb "atendi" in PIV?

Tags: verbs, accusative, transitivity

http://vortaro.net/?w=atendi#atendi

PIV notes that the verb "atendi" is transitive. However, definition 2 ("Prokrasti ian agon ĝis okazos alia ago") has example sentences that do not have anything that I recognise as a direct object (ie, there's no -n).

Example: *mi atendis, ĝis ili ĉesos paroli*

I'm assuming (and only because there doesn't seem to be any other option) that the phrase *"ĝis ili ĉesos paroli"* is some kind of "accusative phrase".

Is this right? Can a better grammarian than me explain?

And as a bonus question, I've taken a phrase from tatoeba (and yes, I understand that is not a reference in itself...) *"tedas atendi"*, which I have taken to mean "it's boring to wait" or "waiting is boring". Is this a correct sentence? Because it sounds like atendi is behaving intransitively here. Or is there an unspoken object *"tedas atendi (on something...)"*? Or should it just be *"tedas atendado"*?

Comment: Just found this discussion in the "related" column: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/where-do-you-put-the-accusative-when-the-object-is-a-sentence?rq=1 ... If the answer there is correct, then perhaps my idea of an "accusative phrase" isn't as stupid as I thought.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is just a case where the object has been elided. For example, in the following phrase:

> Mi ne malsatas, mi jam manĝis

*manĝi* is still transitive despite not having an object because you can assume that they ate *something*, they just haven’t mentioned what.

In your example they are still waiting for something (ie, *atendas ion*) but they haven’t mentioned what. It could be that they *atendis flugantan elefanton*, but given the context you would assume it’s something like:

> Mi atendis [la ĉesigon de ilia parolado] ĝis ili ĉesis paroli

As a further example to show that the part with *ĝis* doesn’t form the object of *atendi*, consider the following example where the object is clearly something different:

> Bob perdiĝis en la ĝangalo. Li atendis helpon ĝis leono manĝis lin.

I think it is the same in your second example, and you are right that there is just an unspoken object.

Comment: That really helps. The *manĝi* example was well chosen and it makes a lot of sense.